# Chaining array of promise returning functions with $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise, q

I have an array of functions, where each function returns `promise` from ajax call.

```
var promises = [];
if (form.$valid) { 
  Object.keys($scope.Model.Data.FormFiles).forEach(function (key) {
    var file = $scope.Model.Data.FormFiles[key];

    function uploadFile(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var upload = Upload.upload({
            url: "/api/ir/funnelApi/UploadFile",
            data: { file: file }
        });

        upload.then(function (response) {                           
                // do something
                deferred.resolve(response.statusText);
            }, function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error.data);
            }, function (evt) {

        });             
        return deferred.promise;
    }       

    promises.push(uploadFile);
  });   
}
```

What i am trying to do is, if all the file has been uploaded successfully then do something.

```
$q.all(promises).then(function (responses) {                    
   // do something
}, function (errors) {
   // if any of the file upload fails, it should come here  
});
```

But the problem is the ajax are **never fired** and the `$q.all` always moves to success with the function array.

**What's the wrong i am doing??**

Comment: does it get inside `deferred.resolve(response.statusText);`? try putting `console.log()` there

Comment: For this to work the parent promise has to be resolved or rejected, can you post the Ajax request code

Comment: It seems the uploadFile function is not called from anywhere. You need to call that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pushing references of the function to array....not invoking the function and pushing the returned promise

Try changing:

```
promises.push(uploadFile);
```

to

```
promises.push(uploadFile());
```

---

Creating a new promise using `$q.defer();` [is also an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) when `Upload.upload()` already returns a promise and you could simply return that instead